# Jump to navigation link

Tags: routes, 7

I would like to add a "Jump to navigation link" to the Utility menu at the top.

Setting the path to "#main-content" doesn't seem to work.

The path '' is either invalid or you do not have access to it.

If I view the source of my page the anchor is there:

Jump to navigation

Why can't I link to #main-content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use the [Menu token](http://drupal.org/project/menu_token) module in order to get the path to the current page as you first need a valid path, and then add your anchor to the path.

The tokenized path for the menu item should be something like:

```
[current-page:url:path]#footer
```

Comment: Thanks for that. So do I put "[current-page:url:path]#footer" in the Path * field?

Comment: Got it!!!! Thank you.
I put [current-page:url:path]#main-content in the Path field. Duhhh!

Comment: How bizzare! It works on the homepage but wipes out ALL the content on all OTHER pages :S

Comment: Even disabling the menu link doesn't bring back the content on pages other than the homepage. I have to remove the link alltogether...

Comment: It's the "Node from context" option under the "Method for Nodes" section that breaks all the pages other than the homepage. Why would this be the case?

They all have the "<a href="#main-menu" class="element-invisible element-focusable">Jump to navigation</a>" in the source code...

Comment: I installed the dev version this time, which then required the entity module. It's an API extension though... I put it in the modules directory. Hope that's ok?
It semi-fixed the issue, in a sense that the rest of the pages now look fine. Except... The new menu with the Skip to link is only displayed on the homepage. I've checked the settings for the Menu block and there is no reason (that I can see) why it would only be displaying on the homepage... ANy ideas?

Comment: I have tried this myself and I had no issues on a rather clean Drupal 7 installation. The only option you need to enable is "Use tokens in title and in path", then it should be fine. You can check if it's working by looking at the url path in the link. It should go to current page. If it's not working there must be some other module or custom code that is interfering.

Comment: Thank you.
The url it points to on the homepage is /node#main-menu.

Comment: CHanging the path to [current-page:url]#main-menu is now displaying the Skip to Navigation link on ALL pages. HOwever, it doesn't do what it's meant to do :S
It doesn't actually skip and take  you to the main menu...

Comment: I did some more testing and you are correct that on the front page the path is /node and as such a page reload is done. Doesn't seem to be a way around this. Other than that, if you have a container with the id `#main-content` I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: [current-page:url]#main-content works!!!
I have the following in the source code:
<a id="main-content"></a>

But how would I go about linking to <a href="#main-menu" class="element-invisible element-focusable">Jump to navigation</a>
Using a separete link of course.

Comment: Got it!
[current-page:url]#superfish-1